# How to select multiselect array type option of searchable option jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, select, input

My select box is multiple selection type select box. I am using "searchable option" library to show select box, which allow search and showing checkbox in front of options "https://pbauerochse.github.io/searchable-option-list/examples.html"

Its working fine, and when I m posting form, i m receiving post variable in the form of array.

Now I am not able to select option via JQuery. I tried to do like this -

```
attachArray = new Array('1','2');
1 - $('[name="resources"]').val( JSON.stringify( attachArray ) );
2 - $('[name="resources"]').val(attachArray);
```

But above two ways not working for me.

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your doom you will need to inspect the radio or checkbox that you want to click, and fake a click using

```
$('.sol-checkbox[value="Chris"]').click();
```

if you are using radio buttons you can use:

```
$('.sol-radio[value="Chris"]').click();
```

This way will emulate a click, on the other hand if you want to select all of them you can use:

```
var selector = $('#my-select').searchableOptionList({
....
});

selector.selectAll();
```